# What is the correct term for the viewing hole in a door?

Tags: terminology

Doors often have a small hole with a fish-eye lens for security purposes. They are commonly called 'peepholes' but I'm sure I have come across a formal architectural term for this type of aperture, possibly Latin or Greek. I can't find it though!

Comment: Apparently [door viewer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-1-in-Big-Eye-Door-Viewer-U-10314/100126851?cm_mmc=Shopping|Base&gclid=CjwKEAjwm-aqBRD39YPqhbzthzYSJACFj-Atr3AFF57CpwdNHFgqajcDXHcgyrMe9kxcNCM6bGMj2RoC797w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) is the "official" term, though I'm not sure how many people would know what it means.

Comment: Since the ancient Romans and Greeks didn't have fish-eye lenses, it seems unlikely they'd have have a word for the modern type of door viewer that depends on them.

Comment: Peephole: 
***opening, crack, hole, aperture, knothole, crevice, eyehole, eyelet, slit, slot, spyhole.***

Comment: Not necessarily with a lens, just the hole itself.

Comment: I'm a technical writer in the construction industry and have seen 'peephole' used in many official/formal documents (UK).

Comment: Fun fact: The French word for the bigger (often square) version of this is *vasistas*, after the German question "Was ist das?" (What's this?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm quite certain that the ancient Romans and Greeks had access to fish-eye lenses.  They just never had occasion to remove them from the fish.

Comment: *peephole* is dated 1680s;  *eyehole* late 15c, it is also called [**speakeasy grill/e**](http://store.tetoniron.com/hardware-speakeasy.html), but Etymonline dates *speakeasy* around 1889; [**Judas hole or Judas slits**](http://www.bartleby.com/81/9333.html) possibly early 19c.

Comment: Is it possible your memory was suggesting the term *oculus*, which is a formal architectural term for a hole? Not really appropriate for a peephole, but memory is a funny thing.

Comment: Could well be yes.

Comment: @HansAdler On that basis wouldn't the peephole be a 'verista' from "Wer ist da" meaning "who is there"?

Comment: @BoldBen: That would be more logical, but that's clearly not how it happened. "Was ist das?" is a common question in German, especially from people who are irritated because something is not as it should be. (British policeman equivalen: "What's all this then?") It is possible that this question first became proverbial in French in some other (war-related) context. It is also possible that the French subsumed other utterances from German soldiers answering the door under this sentence, e.g. "Was ist da schon wieder los?" - "What's going on there again?"

Comment: @HansAdler I think you're probably right that it came from wartime occupation, however my comment wasn't meant to be entirely serious:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had one on the door when I was growing up in the 1960s London and we called it the Vassi. Just checked with my sister and she remembers the same word. Never knew why until I read Hans Adler comment. It was clearly a corruption of ***vasistas***. It was my Grandmother's word as it was her house.

Comment: I see this answer was "accepted" but it doesn't appear to answer the question, which is asking for the *formal* term for these holes.

Comment: Note for authors: destructive edits should not be accepted. An edit stating "this is wrong" should have been another answer; if you feel it's justified you can write the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fine about being wrong but will add I was referring to an opening in the door which Gran called a **Vassi**. It was a small window that could be opened from the inside to allow delivery of small packages. I think I may have misunderstood the original question.